# Django runserver syntax error

Tags: python, django

I have problem with running Django tutorial.
I'm new with command-line stuff but I've really searched for my issue and try everything before I post this.

I've tried tutorial with pools application and I've run 'runserver' before and it worked at beginning (Django default page). When I added urls.py (just like in tutorial) it wasn't worked anymore.
I've figired out the problem was different versions of Python (2.7, 3.1, 3.5), so I uninstall all of them and install only the Python 3.5.

There were some minor problems with permission but I've runned terminal as administrator and seemed to be ok. But now I cannot do 'runserver' anymore.
When I type:

`C:\Users\urszulka\PycharmProjects\DJ\mysite>python manage.py runserver`

I've got:

```
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x039A5858>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 658, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 764, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\urszulka\PycharmProjects\DJ\mysite\mysite\urls.py", line 1
    pythjo`"""mysite URL Configuration
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why syntax error? I've done everything like before.
I'll be really pleased with your help.

Comment: I think you accidentally typed `pythjo` in your urls.py

Comment: You need to show the code that's failing, not just the error message.

Comment: I've already found this typo and fixed this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typos in file `DJ\mysite\mysite\urls.py`. Looks like the line 1 was scrambled because you type something random like `pythjo` and that's not valid python syntax.